# How can I completely remove wireless drivers?

Tags: networking, wireless

On my laptop the wireless seems to be detected but it fails to connect. Even turning the switch on and off seems to have no effect. This is the output of lspci command:

```
06:02.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4318 [AirForce One 54g] 802.11g Wireless LAN Controller (rev 02)
```

I have the package b43-fwcutter istalled. Some people told me if I remove the linux driver and  install Ndiswrapper the proplem would be solved. Is that true? And if the answer is yes how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx) that explains all the details of making this wireless chip work on different Ubuntu releases.